# Continuity of the tangent and normal cone mappings

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, set-valued-analysis

I am exploring the continuity of tangent and normal cone mappings to a nonempty compact set $X$ at $x\in X$; that is, let $T(x;X)$ and $N(x;X)$ respectively denote the tangent and normal cone to $X$ at $x$. $T(x^k;X)\to T(x^*;X)$ and $N(x^k;X)\to N(x^*; X)$ as $x^k\to x^*$.

Is it generally guaranteed? I could not find any results discussing the continuity.

The motivation of the question is to identify the continuity of the sum of a continuous mapping $\Phi\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ and the normal cone $N(x;X)$, i.e., $\Phi(x)+N(x;X)$.

Comment: What kind of convergence of sets are you interested in? Are you assuming $K$ convex?Also: think about these cones for $X = [0,1]^2$.